# How to install libjpeg?

Tags: python, pip, libjpeg

I tried these commands:

```
pip install libjpeg8-dev
pip install libjpeg-dev
pip install libjpeg-devel
pip install libjpeg
pip install libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev
```

but none of them works. What is the right command with pip?

Comment: If you want to manipulate images using python, use the "Python Imaging library".

Comment: PIL requires libjpeg for jpg-related stuff

Comment: Usually (at least on Linux and *BSD and OSX) it is the job of the package management system to deal with such things.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`libjpeg` is not a python module and pip won't ever be able to install it.

Use your Operating System's packaging system to install it. On Ubuntu and Debian that'd be apt, for example.

Comment: In the ideal case PIL should have option to download libjpeg and install together :)

Answer (score 49):

Use apt-get. As a side note, I was getting errors installing pillow and these commands helped me

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

I used homebrew to install that!

```
brew install libjpeg
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Actually I use Heroku and the problem therefore is more complicated. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213509/python-pil-and-jpeg-on-heroku) is a solution.
EDIT: but attempts to use both hg- and git-based variants failed with various errors. Damn!

Answer (score 0):

If you are running other weird OS like Red Hat you can also try:
`yum install libjpeg-devel zlib-devel`